# Self Join Table To Produce The Output MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, join, self

Could you please help produce the output table from the below input table(screenshots are provided.Basically I would need to get the pcn from the cn based on the pid in each row.I used a case when statement but the data is huge and it's not a sustainable way,hence the self join would be fine.But I am not getting the expected output from the below self join query

Here is the self join query I tried.

```
select b.id, b.cn, a.pid, a.cn as pcn 
from ( 
   (select pid,cn from categories) a 
   left join (select id,cn from categories) b on a.pid=b.id 
)
```

Here is the case statement I used for deriving data for some of the data

```
select id,cn,pid,
       case 
          when pid is NULL then cn 
          when pid=1 then (select cn from categories where id=1) 
          when pid=13 then (select cn from categories where id=13) 
       END as pcn 
from categories
```

[image: inputtable]

[image: outputtable]

Comment: Please don't use images, and put your query in the question, not in a comment :)

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need to nest sub-selects to join tables. Your first query can be simplified to `from categories a left join categories b on a.pid = b.id`

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: yes you are right..I should have avoided sub selection from the tables to join it.Also I added tag for the database product.

Comment: @Liora Haydont : I could not paste the data in the tabular format ,that is why added the image.however the query was added to the question itself.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT i.id, i.cn, i.pid, c.cn
FROM inputTable i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c ON (i.pid = c.id)
```

Comment: Exactly..but had to alter as below to handle the NULL columns.If the pid is null then it should take the i.cn
 SELECT 
 i.id,
  i.cn, 
  i.pid, 
  case when i.pidis null then i.cn else c.cn end as pcn
FROM inputtable i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c ON (i.pid= c.id)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  i.id,
  i.cn,
  i.pid,
  i2.cn as pcn
from input_table i
  left join input_table i2
    on i.pid=i2.id
```

Comment: Exactly.Thanks alot..but had to alter as below to handle the NULL columns.If the pid is null then it should take the i.cn
 SELECT 
 i.id,
  i.cn, 
  i.pid, 
  case when i.pidis null then i.cn else i2.cn end as pcn
FROM inputtable i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN inputtable i2ON (i.pid= i2.id)

Answer (score 0):

The below query could give me the exact expected results.Thanks to Jaime ,jhilden and a_horse_with_no_name                                                                            SELECT
i.id,                                                                         i.cn,
i.pid,                                                                         case when i.pid is null then i.cn else i2.cn end as pcn
FROM inputtable i LEFT OUTER JOIN inputtable i2 ON (i.pid= i2.id)